# crontab versus /etc/cron.d

Tags: raspbian, ubuntu

I tried `crontab -e` and the file that was edited is `/tmp/crontab.vJdE7J/crontab`.  Is this correct?

I read from http://www.devils-heaven.com/raspberry-pi-cron-jobs/ that I should be creating a schedule file in `/etc/cron.d` instead.

I tried the first method, and couldn't verify that any scheduled task was run.  I tried the second method and it worked for me.  When I added a second file in /etc/cron.d, it was not run.  Is there a need to reinitialize the cron process?  Or does /etc/cron.d allow only one cron file?

Comment: This would probably fit better on [unix.se] as that is a Linux-centric Stack Exchange site and this is a generic Linux question, not Raspberry Pi-specific. However, if you've used these exact commands on another Linux system and haven't had issues there, then this question would be on-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `crontab -e`, make changes, and then save, it saves the new crontab into a temporary file, presumably does a little verification, then automatically copies the temporary file to the proper location.

You seem to be describing normal `crontab -e` behaviour.

Use `crontab -l` to see if your changes were properly committed.